# android:implementing google maps(upload image on ballon overlay click)

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an app in which i have to use gogglemaps and i am showing pin to show current place.Now i want that when i click on yellow image it should redirect to the gallery and from gallery user can select image and it should be uploaded in place of yellow image.Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

[image]  Basically **on click on yellow butoon i want to open gallery and let the user to upload this picture.**

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a custom overlay class (which extends ItemizedOverlay) and override it's onTap method to do what you want.

Comment: which yellow image? do you mean the pin?